# I just don't understand $.fn in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with this syntax?

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.fn.myfunction(myparam) {
        alert(myparam);
        return 0; // return jQuery?
    }
    myfunction('Hello World');
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to learn how to extend jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is trying to call a method called `myFunction` on the `jQuery.fn` reference.

To extend the jQuery object, you want this syntax:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.fn.myfunction = function(myparam) {
        alert(myparam);
        return this; // returns the current jQuery object.
    }

    // Select something with jQuery using the $() function here.
    $().myfunction('Hello World');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction(myparam) {
```

should be

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction = function(myparam) {
```

as you are assigning the property `myfunction` of object `jQuery.fn` a value of `function () {...`

Answer (score 3):

A method defined via jQuery.myFunction is a "static" function.  You call it by doing $.yourFunction, and it's not tied to a result set.

Conversely, a function defined on jQuery.fn.myFunction is a tied to a result set; if you do "this" within that function, you'll get the jQuery object that was used to call it.  In other words, if you do $("P").myFunction() "this" in my Function will be $("P").

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation...

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  check: function() {
    return this.each(function() { this.checked = true; });
  },
  uncheck: function() {
    return this.each(function() { this.checked = false; });
  }
});
```

See more [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.fn.extend).

Comment: Chalkey: I am coming to you for help because I don't understand the jQuery documentation.

Comment: What you want is to give the jQuery.fn.[you_function] a function... such that jQuery.fn.example = function() { document.write('example'); return this; } ... The returning this will allow you to chain jQuery objects together. You have probably seen something like $('#div#').hide().show('slow'); etc.

Comment: I was looking for the exact syntax because it seems that you can do anything you want in jQuery - all you need is a couple of squiggly lines, curly brackets, braces and parentheses and bam!  There you have it.